# MVT on a logarithmic function and the domain used.

Tags: calculus

I came across this question in a discussion forum: 
Use the mean value theorem to show that

$ln (\frac{(x +1)}{x}) \lt \frac{1}{x}$ for  $x \gt 0.$

I defined f(x) as the product xln(x + 1) and i  need to show that there exists a c > 0 such that the derivative of f at c is less than 1.

I am i justified to do this and then what happens next..?  would you give just a hint.

Comment: Why have considered  f(x)=xln(x+1)? your starting point is not clear

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$f(x)=\log x$$

The MVT gives

$$\log(x+1)-\log x=\frac{1}{c}$$

for $x<c<x+1$.

And $\frac{1}{c}<\frac{1}{x}$.

Can you finish?

Comment: yes , i can now finish. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

you have $$\ln\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)= \ln(x+1) - \ln x = \int_x^{x+1} \frac{dt}t = \frac1c < \frac1 x, \text{ since } x < c < x+1.$$

Comment: this is very helpful.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$
\ln(\frac{x+1}{x}) = \ln(x+1) - \ln(x) = \frac{\ln(x+1) - \ln(x)}{(x+1) - x}
$$

and then think about the interval $[x, x+1]$. What's the derivative of $\ln(x)$ there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to start with something obvious from the 
graphs of $y=x-1$ and $y=\ln x$ (and easy to prove if necessary), 
then start with the inequality: 
$$\ln x\le x-1,\ \ \  x>0$$.

[image: $\ln x\le x-1,\ \ \ x>0$]

Rewrite as $\ln t\le t-1$ where $t>0$ and let $z=t-1$, so 
$\ln (z+1)\le z$. Next let $z=\dfrac1x$ so $\ln (\dfrac{x+1}x)=\ln (1+\dfrac1x)\le \dfrac1x$.

Oops, I was supposed to use the MVT ... I guess I did use it ... tacitly ...